# How to Count Bits from multiple Hexadecimals

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have 16 Hex values, I need to count the total number of Bits (1's)

```
#I have tried this

val = hex(bus.read_port(0))+hex(bus.read_port(1)) #There are 16 ports.

#read port returns a Decimal (0-255)
#val is 0x3f0xff

def bitCount(val):
    count = bin(val).count('1')
    return (count)

#bitCount() Returns 6 instead of 14
```

But it returns only the first byte's bits.
Printing val before returns e.g. 0x3f0xff
What I need is 3F00FF instead (The binary value of each hex stringed together into one hex)
Or another way to read the combined number of bits.

This seemed to work but I get 10 instead of 16

```
bus.write_port(0, 0xFF)
bus.write_port(1, 0xFF)

def popcount255(k):
    k = (k & 15) + (k >> 4)
    k = (k & 3) + (k >> 2)
    return (k & 1) + (k >> 1)

def bitCount():
    result = popcount255(bus.read_port(0)) + popcount255(bus.read_port(1))
    return (result)

if True:
    print "BitCount ", bitCount()
```

I'm getting a Count of 10?

This is working now

```
def bitCount():
    result = bin(bus_1.read_port(0)).count('1') + bin(bus_1.read_port(1)).count('1')
return (result)
```

Comment: Well `0x3f0xff` does not makes any sense.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to put the original question back up, followed by your additional code and questions about getting @WillemVanOnsem's method to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert to a hex string to get the bit count, just convert both values straight to binary strings, count the 1s in each, and add the two results:

```
bitCount = bin(bus.read_port(0)).count('1') + bin(bus.read_port(1)).count('1')
```

Alternatively, if you really want to compute `val = '0x3FFF'` to pass to your original `bitCount()` function, you could do:

```
val = hex((bus.read_port(0) << 8) + bus.read_port(1))
```

Which works like this:

```
  --> hex((0x3F << 8) + 0xFF)
  --> hex(0x3F00 + 0xFF)
  --> hex(0x3FFF)
  --> '0x3FFF'
```

What you were doing was concatenating two hex strings, hence your issues:

```
val = hex(bus.read_port(0)) + hex(bus.read_port(0))

  --> hex(0x3F) + hex(0xFF)
  --> '0x3F' + '0xFF'        # string concatenation
  --> '0x3F0xFF'             # not '0x3FFF', extra '0x' in the middle
```

Note that `'0x3F0xFF'` is not a valid string representation of a hex number (trying to convert it to binary using `bin()` was only seeing the first `'0x3F'` part before the unexpected `'0x'` in the middle, hence why `count('1')` was returning `6`).

Comment: Thank you that works Perfectly for what i want to do, didn't realize you could do it like that .

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are some strange things here:

1. whether the number is represented as decimal, or hexadecimal, does not matter when you count the set bits;
2. by using `hex(..)` you convert it to a string; and
3. later you concatenate these strings, making the result something that is not a hexadecimal value.

We can implement a `popcount` for values up to 255 (or a constant *k* bits) in *O(log k)*:

```
def popcount255(k):
    k = (k & 85) + ((k & 170) >> 1)
    k = (k & 51) + ((k & 204) >> 2)
    return (k & 15) + ((k & 240) >> 4)
```

So we can then use this function to count the set bits:

```
result = popcount255(bus.read_port(0)) + popcount255(bus.read_port(1))
```

Comment: I am trying you method.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your `popcount255`. `popcount255(0b111)` gives me 2. Or am I missing something obvious? OP's `bin(k).count('1')` looks rather ok to me - as long as you feed it an `int`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: you are correct. I implemented the algorithm more or less in reverse. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: Interesting algo.I take it it is "pseudo"-O(log k), actually linear once you exceed the bit length of your architecture's `int`? No criticism, just curious.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: yes, since in Python-3.x, the bitwise operations work on arbitrary length numbers. But in case the `int` has a fixed number of bits, and bitwise operations are constant time, then the algorithm can be generalized to work in *O(log k)* operations.